# Improving my current database design to store employees' schedules

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I need to come up with a software able to store employees' schedules in a database. I currently have this design:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedules` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `employee_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
   `day_of_week` int(2) NOT NULL,
   `starting_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
   `ending_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Pretty straight forward. Print today's date, figure out what is the day of the week, and retrieve all matches from database, but I'd like to know a better way to achieve the same thing.

I need to display on a calendar employees' schedules and I need to pass a date to the calendar in order to be displayed. However, I cannot pass a date to the calendar if the only information I know is that a given employee is going to work on Wednesday.

Given the latter database design, is there a way to retrieve all the Wednesdays, or Mondays of a month/year?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I need help going backwards (or a better alternative) to change day of the week to actual dates.

These are my "restrictions":

- My calendar control requires a date in order to display an "event" in the UI.
- Employees should submit their schedule just once.

For instance:
John Doe works Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays. 8:00 - 12:00.

That information, with my current database design, is represented in the following fashion:

```
ID, employee_id, day_of_week, starting_time, ending_time
1, John Doe, 1, 8:00, 12:00
2, John Doe, 3, 8:00, 12:00
3, John Doe, 5, 8:00, 12:00
```

I need to be able to pass a date to the calendar UI for a given month.

For instance I should be able to come up with a way to tell my calendar control:
John Doe is going to work on the 6th, 13th, 20th, and 27th taking in consideration that the only information I have is "day_of_week" = 1 (Mondays)

**EDIT 2**

My current but ugly solution is:
Loop through all the days of the month, and query the database day by day.

**EDIT 3 - SOLUTION**

Thanks to RS, I was able to solve my problem. 
I kept the `schedules` table as it was, but I created the tables suggested by *rs* 
After creating the tables described on the article shared by *rs*
The following query did the job:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(users.firstname,\" \",users.lastname) as employee_name, 
 DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%a %b %d %Y') as date, schedules.starting_time,
 schedules.ending_time FROM dates_d 
 RIGHT JOIN schedules ON schedules.day_of_week = dates_d.day_of_week
 LEFT  JOIN users ON schedules.employee_id = users.ID
```

I JSON-Encoded an array, and the Calendar Control finally worked like a charm.

Comment: you can create date table and use key from that table and store here. The date table will allow you to query data by different date variables, ex: day, week, day of week, quarter etc - http://www.dwhworld.com/2010/08/date-dimension-sql-scripts-mysql/

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more, I think I more or less understand your point.

Comment: SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE day_of_week=DAYOFWEEK('2007-02-03'); will allow you to get schedule for a specific date. DAYOFWEEK gives 1-Monday to 7-Sunday (unlike php's date() which is Sunday-Saturday)

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing to display today's schedules, but they need to see *at least* current month's schedule.

My Calendar control requires a date, or a range of dates in order to display them, but I cannot pass a date to the Calendar control if the only information I have is "Joe works on Wednesdays"
Since day_of_week only stores numbers 1 through 7

Comment: @alancahvez your `schedules` will have `id, emplid, date_id` and you can join `schedules` with `date` table on `schedules.date_id = datetble.date_id` and get `date, day of week` in one query. You can then use this date field with your control

Comment: Are you ever going to want to look at past schedules?  If so, you'll want at least a column for the effective date of that particular schedule.  This so that if Joe worked on Wednesdays from 2012-01-01 to 2012-06-30, but then his schedule changed to Thursdays starting 2012-07-01, you'd have all that information, in case the cops ask you what Joe's schedule was on May 3, when Joe's wife was murdered. And rs is right that to build your monthly schedule, you'll want a table of all dates that you might care about, you pick the month's worth from that, then join to your schedule table based on DOW.

Comment: I am not sure if they ever going to look at past schedules. I was thinking about that in the original design, but this is one of those clients that want everything done by tomorrow because they can do it in Excel in 30 minutes or so.

Comment: @rs I got it now!
I have a table with all the information I need in order to retrieve efficiently all the info I need! Thanks a lot! You should post that as an answer so I can select it as the best.

Comment: @AlanChavez i posted my comments as an answer. Glad my suggestion helped you solve your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create date table and use key from that table and store here. The date table will allow you to query data by different date variables, ex: `day, week, day of week, quarter` etc - dwhworld.com/2010/08/date-dimension-sql-scripts-mysql

your `schedules` table will have `id, emplid, date_id` and you can join `schedules` with `date` table on `schedules.date_id = datetble.date_id` and get date, day of week in one query. You can then use this date field with your control

Answer (score 1):

Why not have your **day_of_week** column a **date** type instead, that way if you want to get the day from this date you can use MySQL's [DayOfWeek](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function.  You could use this same date to pass to your calendar control (I think that's what you were getting at) in your UI.

To elaborate on your comment: Wouldn't the date that John Doe is scheduled to work be entered by the user (possibly via [jQuery UI's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)), then when rendering your schedule at the UI level you'd use the following query to retrieve their monday schedule:

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedules 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(schedule_date) = 1
AND employee_id = (
    SELECT employee_id
    FROM employees
    WHERE employee_name = 'John Doe'
)
```

Obviously this query makes some assumptions on your **employees** table, and it's not particularly elegant but it serves to explain my meaning.

**RE: EDIT**

OK, now I see what you mean. Basically you're after a function that will give you all dates between two ranges (perhaps) that land on a specified day (let's say monday).  It seems this  [has already been done in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045736/getting-all-dates-for-mondays-and-tuesdays-for-the-next-year) so that might be useful? Or do have a specific technology in mind that this would need to be done in?

**EDIT 3**

This seems a more elegant solution: [Get mondays tuesdays etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362298/get-mondays-tuesdays-etc) - from this you can query your DayOfWeek in the SQL and return an array of integers that you can pass as the third argument to their function.

Comment: Not a fan of this, as DOW is the desired value to work from, so calculating it for every entry in the schedule is unnecessary.

Comment: @Waygood What I'm not sure about, is which week are they referring to... what date?  I can't see a date column in that table.  I know they've said "print today's date" so I assume they're always going to be going off the current week.  This vastly limits the scope of their program, what about historical data?  What if there was a requirement to see who has worked what in the past X months.  I think, despite the small overhead of calculating the DOW each time, is worth it for the potential feature gain.

Comment: The function to know the DayOfWeek is not the problem, my problem is going backwards, or I don't know if I'm not getting the point.

The final user needs to put his/her schedule just once, I don't want the final user to put his/her schedule every week.

Comment: @Terric, exactly! I want to use a date field, but I don't know how to use it, or implement it.

Comment: @AlanChavez Who is creating this database structure, I assumed it was yourself?  What exactly do you need help with, is it the query to generate the table structure and / or the way of writing from PHP the date into your database?  Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @Terric regarding your answer, I do not know what date to store. 

Let's say that John Doe stores "August 8th, 2012" from that date, how can the software "know" that John Doe is scheduled to work on Mondays?

Comment: I'm going to edit the post, since the comment field is not big enough to put a good explanation.

Comment: I just updated my question, your answer shows more or less what I'm currently doing.

Comment: @Terric 
That's more or less what I'm currently doing as well... I think my code is slightly cleaner than the one proposed on the link you shared. 
I really appreciate your help, and concern. It seems that I'll need to loop through the whole month and query database 31 times before displaying data.

Comment: @AlanChavez another edit, any use?  Sorry I can't remember much of PHP's syntax and am not in a position to hash out much code at the moment.